# Java Swing Combobox with Autocomplete and Context Menu

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox

I have auto complete for a JCombobox working by following this article:

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/07/19/adding-auto-completion-to-swing-comboboxes.html

I am using the SwingX library.

Now I would like to add persistence support to the items in the combo box. Basically when you right click an item a context menu comes up and you can remove the item. The same thing with the delete key.

To add an item the user just types a new entry which in not in the list yet.

I haven’t found a way to hook up a context menu yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add key listener on combo box to look for delete key. As for the popup, you'll have to implement it by yourself.